# How to get total document count from multiple collection using stream expression in solr?

Tags: solr

I am trying to load data from multiple collections from solr cloud using stream expressions and also  able to load it successfully.
Here along with response, I also wanted to get total documents count for matched documents in both collections.

**For example:**

**document**- collection

**folder** - collection

Common field in both collection is **folder_id**

Using below query I am able to load match document from both collection based on common field but I also wanted to load total document count for listing.

```
innerJoin(search(document,
                   q="query filter for document collection",
                    fl="fields",
                    sort="folder_id desc"),
         search(folder,
                 q="query filter to match data in folder collection",
                 fl="fields"
                ,sort="folder_id desc"),
                       on="folder_id")
```

Is there any way to get total documents count in same result set ??

Thanks in advance !